# How to Automate Azure DNS zones backup into Storage account using PowerShell runbook

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli, azure-automation

I am trying to automate the Azure DNS Zones Backup into Azure Storage account using automation account.I wanted to create a PowerShell runbook which gets all DNS zones and export the zone file of zones and upload them into storage account.

```
#Authentication
Connect-AzAccount
Set-AzContext -Subscription mysubscriptiom

#Variables
$storageAccountName = "dnszonesbackup"
$storageAccountKey = "key"
$containerName = "dns-backups"

#Logic
$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey
$zones = Get-AzDnsZone
foreach ($zone in $zones) {
    $zoneFile = "Here i am stuck, How to export a zone files of DNS Zones and pass into blob storage"
    $blobName = $zone.Name + ".zone"
    Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Context $context -Container $containerName -File $zoneFile -Blob $blobName
}
```

However when I am trying export the zone file I couldn't find any export cmdlet. Is there any possible way to achieve this.

Comment: [It looks like you can achieve this with Az CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-import-export) but not Powershell

Comment: @AnthonyNorwood can we achieve an automation using az cli in automation account or another service to backup AZ DNS Zones. Is it Possible

Comment: It looks like you can't use Az CLI in an automation runbook, at least a Powershell one, but you could use Get-AzDNSZone to get all zones, then iterate through that list passing each zone to Get-AzDNSRecordSet and converting the output to JSON to store in blob storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However when I am trying export the zone file I couldn't find any export cmdlet. Is there any possible way to achieve this.

I have uploaded **Azure DNS** information to **Azure Blob** using an automation runbook.

> Note: You can schedule the script to run automatically at a specific time to upload the Azure DNS information to Azure blob.

**Powershell Code.**

```
$Appid = "APPID"
$PSWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "APSecret" -AsPlainText -Force
$tenantID = "TenantID"
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList $Appid,$PSWord
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $Credential -Tenant   $tenantID -ServicePrincipal -Subscription "SubscriptionID"
Set-AzContext -Tenant $tenantID
$storageAccountName = "storageaccount name"
$storageAccountKey = "storageaccount key"
$containerName = "containername"
$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey
$zones = Get-AzDnsZone
foreach ($zone in $zones) {
    $recordSets = Get-AzDnsRecordSet -ZoneName $zone.Name -ResourceGroupName $zone.ResourceGroupName
    $json = $recordSets | ConvertTo-Json
    $jsonR = ConvertFrom-Json $json
    $jsonR | Export-Csv "DNS.csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation
  $result = Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Context $context -Container "venkat" -File "DNS.csv" -Blob "DNS.csv" -Force
}
$result
```

**Automation runbook output:**

[image]

After running the code from the azure automation account, the file was successfully uploaded to the Azure blob.

[image]

Thanks to `Anthony Norwood` for suggesting the same.

Comment: Thanks @VenkatV the above solution works perfectly. However I have made little tweaks on the above code. In `Set-AzStorageBlobContent` updated with `-Force` so that it will overrides the existing file. Also Added `-Append` for JSON. which will append the multiple DNS Zone entries to the same file

Comment: @AnthonyNorwood While running the the above solution I am stuck with system.obejcts[] issue and I cant view the records properly in the blob due to it. Any idea or suggestion how to upload from json to csv based on the above approach